# Adding android notification that notifies at a given time

Tags: android, notifications

I want to add my app a feature wherein it will show a notification at a particular time, I.e. When the patient needs to take a medicine it will show a notification based on a given time. Where can i have a complete tutorial? Thanks =D

Comment: Please read over [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) can be used to schedule when you want the notification to occur. Details about how to create notifications are available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html).